# Copy files modified in last 2 days

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I would like to copy files between folders. Just **modified** (CSV files with new entries) in current day and one day before.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2")) {
    if ($file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) {
        Copy-Item -Path "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" -Destination "\\Oracle\MP"
        "copying $file"
    } else {
        "not copying $file"
    }
}
```

What is wrong - any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Script to copy files based on date modifed to check newest file from a remote location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421519/powershell-script-to-copy-files-based-on-date-modifed-to-check-newest-file-from)

Comment: So you would only like to copy files that have been modified?  You don't use `$file` in the `Copy-Item` line.

Comment: @Mr Tree, Yes only files that have been modified.

Comment: @UrhLednik and did you mean last 24 hours or all of yesterday and today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare the date with `-gt` otherwise your're looking for files that were copied at that EXACT time.

Note that doing `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` is perfectly valid but will give you anything modified in the last 24 hours.

```
$DestinationFolder = "\\Oracle\MP\"
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)
$Files = Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" 
foreach ($File in $Files) {
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime)
    {
        Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestinationFolder
        Write-Host "Copying $File"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Not copying $File"
    }
}
```

If you didn't want to write out the "Copying ..." and "Not Copying ..." then you could simplify this quite a bit.

```
$DestingationFolder = "\\Oracle\MP\"
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1) 
Get-ChildItem -File |? { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime } | Copy-Item -Destination $DestingationFolder
```

Finally, if you want to copy anything since the beginning of (eg midnight at the start of) yesterday then change the following line:

```
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1).Date
```

Comment: Just call the Date property to get 'midnight': (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date

Comment: @Mr Tree and nimizen Thanks answers. It works to me.

Comment: I got an error `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.` so I omitted `-File` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

@Mr Tree I have one more related question.

I got few times per day new file at the location D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-HT (location 1) with fixed name abcDD.MM.YYYY.csv (abc03.09.2015.csv) and I have a service which every 10 minutes call my powershell script below. I made as you suggest before in upper posts. My goal is: 1. to check if there is new file with name abcDD.MM.YYYY.csv | 2. rename it into abcDD.MM.YYYYHT.csv and move it to "\Oracle\MP\PURO\" (location 2) folder where I need to rewrite it with existing for current day.

Problem is that if the file already exists on the location 2, script does not want to move it and rewrite it? Thanks for hints.

```
$DestingationFolder = "\\Oracle\MP\PURO\"
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)

Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-HT\*.csv" | ?{!($_.fullname -match "HT\.csv")} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.csv", "HT.csv" }

$Files = Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-HT\*.csv" -File

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime)
    {
        Move-Item $File -Destination $DestingationFolder
        Write-Host "Moving $File"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Not moving $File"
    }
}
```