# Batch Script to copy folders with files having a specific date and format from one location to another a

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to copy all the folders in a source path which have files older than 365 days and of specific formats (.docx,.xlsx and .txt) to another location .
I need to copy the entire folder and not only the files. 
Since this is my first time in Windows batch scripting, I was able to only write a command to just echo the path of  the files of one particular format and older than 365 days as given below:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\PRATIK\Documents\Test" /s /m *.txt* /D -365 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

But I dont know how to copy the folders having these files and also not know how to copy files of multiple formats.

Would highly appreciate if anyone can guide me regarding this.

p.s: I found the above script in Stack overflow only.Hence thought would find some more details here also.

Comment: You can do it in PowerShell.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421519/powershell-script-to-copy-files-based-on-date-modifed-to-check-newest-file-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `robocopy`, per default included in Windows, which offers a lot of selection criteria like filename patterns, age, size,...
Use it like this:

```
robocopy source_root dest_root *.pdf *.txt /minage:365 /S /L
```

This will copy files matching `*.pdf` or `*.txt` in the folder `source_root` or its subfolders (`/S`) which are older than 365 days (`minage`). With additional options you can take care of daylight savings time. The destination folder (`dest_root`) does not have to exist in advance.

Remove `/L` once you are sure it works like intended - `/L` will only list the files and folders which would have been copied but will prevent the copy process itself.
**edit:**
Source or destination folder can also be UNC paths, that is, "\\server\share\path".
See, for example, https://static.spiceworks.com/attachments/post/0016/6764/robocopy.pdf for reference.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this.. it worked exactly as needed..Hopefully it will work well while copying between servers..

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

If you want to copy all the contents of a folder to another folder while retaining the permissions of its contents, you can do this command.

```
xcopy C:\Location1 C:\Location2 /O /X /E /H /K /C
```

If you would like to copy the files from a specific date or later (or earlier),
you can use the

```
/D:m-d-y
```

switch to specify the date.

**Method 2:**

If you would like to do it the way you already created, you can try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /p "C:\Location1" /s /D -365 /C "cmd /c echo @path"') do (
set file=%%i
copy "%file%" "C:\Location2"
)
pause
```